# .append() with class

Tags: jquery, append

I want to use `.append()` to add a new row to a table. However, the `class="addRowDemo3"` and `class="removeRowDemo3"` are not appended. Any ideas of why?

```
$('.addRowDemo3').click(function(){
    $('#Demo3 > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Google</td><td>12.3</td><td>14.5</td><td>17.3</td><td>20.2</td><td><button class="addRowDemo3">Add a row</button><button class="removeRowDemo3">Remove a row</button></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: The classes are appended, your problem is that the event is not bound to these new button elements, because they did not exist when the event listener was created.

Answer (score 5):

The buttons to add and remove row with the correct classes should be appended. But the event is not bound to the new elements.

When you use $('selector').click(function(){}), only the elements which are currently available in the DOM and matched by the selector are bound to the event handler.

For future elements try using jQuery "on":

Try this

```
$('#Demo3').on('click', '.addRowDemo3', function(){
    $('#Demo3 > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Google</td><td>12.3</td><td>14.5</td><td>17.3</td><td>20.2</td><td><button class="addRowDemo3">Add a row</button><button class="removeRowDemo3">Remove a row</button></td></tr>');
});
```

This way you are delegating the event upto '#Demo3'. Whenever you click a '.addRowDemo3', newly added or existing, the event bubbles upto '#Demo3' and your function is executed

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Beat me to it!  Should probably explain that the classes aren't being recognized because the script has already been run.

Comment: @labrro This doesn't work for me. The add function is not working for any one of the rows...

Answer (score 0):

Seeem to work fine for me, what is different in your code?

http://jsfiddle.net/CV3kp/

Here is a version using on as labroo and daedalus suggest and probably what you actually want

http://jsfiddle.net/HWRhX/1/

Comment: Did you perchance click the button on the dynamically added rows?

Comment: @Daedalus - I didn't have to, those won't do anything, but the OP was asking about the "class".  The colors on the new row look fine.